# How to Successfully Plot a Choropleth Using gv.Polygons Instead of gv.Shape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, projection, holoviz, geoviews

---

- Update 20/02/20 after further testing:

I have 2 other shapefiles (one for UK by Postcode Area and one by Parl Constituency). When using gv.Shape with these I do not need to set the projection used to plot successfully, unlike with the one discussed in my original post. 
I can also successfully produce choropleths for these using gv.Polygons:

[image]
[image]

When I checked the projection used by these it was `{'init': 'epsg:4326'}` so I changed the projection on my lad19 shapefile to match that:

`gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=4326)`

however when I attempted to produce the choropleth using gv.Polygons it failed with the same error as the first one that I documented previously.

This feel likes I am close to a solution, does any one have any suggestions?

---

- Original Start:

I have downloaded this UK shapefile:
https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/local-authority-districts-december-2019-boundaries-uk-buc

I can successfully create an interactive UK Choropleth using the following code (**gv.Shape method**):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import random
import copy
import feather
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.feature as gf
import geoviews.tile_sources as gvts
import cartopy
import cartopy.feature as cf
from geoviews import opts
from holoviews import opts, streams
from holoviews.plotting.links import DataLink
from cartopy import crs as ccrs
import hvplot.pandas # noqa
import colorcet as cc
from colorcet.plotting import swatch
sns.set_style()
hv.extension("bokeh","plotly") 

# TO SET NUMBER OF ROWS DISPLAYED:
pd.set_option("display.min_rows",0)
# TO SET NUMBER OF COLUMNS DISPLAYED:
pd.set_option("display.max_columns",0)
```

```py
# LOAD SHAPEFILE USING gv.Shape
In [3]: shapefile = "../level3_LAD19_CONTAINS_4_LE
   ...: VELS_OF_DETAIL/Local_Authority_Districts_December_2019_Boundaries_UK_BUC
   ...: /Local_Authority_Districts_December_2019_Boundaries_UK_BUC.shp" 
   ...: gv.Shape.from_shapefile(shapefile, crs=ccrs.OSGB())                     
Out[3]: :Polygons   [Longitude,Latitude]
```

[image]

```py
In [4]: # IDENTIFY WHICH ATTRIBUTES ARE IN SHAPEFILE - SO WE KNOW WHICH ATTRIBUTE TO JOIN ON:   
   ...: shapes = cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader(shapefile) 
   ...: list(shapes.records())[0]                                               
Out[4]: <Record: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x1c34bc0550>, {'objectid': 1, 'lad19cd': 'E06000001', 'lad19nm': 'Hartlepool', 'lad19nmw': None, 'bng_e': 447160, 'bng_n': 531474, 'long': -1.27018, 'lat': 54.67614, 'st_areasha': 96845510.24630864, 'st_lengths': 50305.32505760145}, <fields>>
```

```py
# LOAD DF THAT CONTAINS ALL 382 UK LOCAL AUTHORITY DISTRICTS:
In [5]: demo_file = pd.read_feather("../stack_overflow_demo_190320.feather") 
   ...: demo_file.head()                                                               
Out[5]: 
  lad19_code      lad19_name          geography  total_population
0  E06000047   County Durham  Unitary Authority            526980
1  E06000005      Darlington  Unitary Authority            106566
2  E06000001      Hartlepool  Unitary Authority             93242
3  E06000002   Middlesbrough  Unitary Authority            140545
4  E06000057  Northumberland  Unitary Authority            320274
```

```py
# SUCCESSFULLY PLOT UK CHOROPLETH:
In [6]: lad19_heatmap = gv.Shape.from_records( 
   ...:     shapes.records(),  
   ...:     demo_file,  
   ...:     on={"lad19cd":"lad19_code"}, 
   ...:     value="total_population", 
   ...:     index="lad19_name", label = "Local Authority Districts UK Population", 
   ...:     crs=ccrs.OSGB()).opts(tools=["hover","tap"], 
   ...:                           cmap = "Reds", colorbar=True, 
   ...:                           hover_line_color="blue", hover_alpha=0.2, 
   ...:                           line_width = 2, show_legend=True, 
   ...:                           legend_position="top", 
   ...:                           width = 600, height = 800) 
   ...:  
   ...: lad19_heatmap                                                                                            
Out[6]: :Polygons   [Longitude,Latitude]   (lad19_name,total_population)
```

[image]

My issue is that I want to move towards a more interactive plot, whereby the user selects a Polygon on the map on the left and a table and/or some other plots appear on the right for the given polygon / Local Authority District as per:
http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/choropleth_data_link.html

To do this I had to switch from using gv.Shape to gv.Polygons and no matter what I try I can not get it to successfully work.

---

**Unsuccessful gv.Polygons Method**:

```py
# LOAD MY SHAPEFILE AS A GEOPANDAS DATAFRAME:
In [10]: gdf = gpd.read_file("../level3_LAD19_CONTAINS_4_LEVELS_OF_DETAIL/Local_Aut
    ...: hority_Districts_December_2019_Boundaries_UK_BUC/Local_Authority_Districts_December_2019_Boundaries_UK_B
    ...: UC.shp") 
    ...: gdf.head()
Out[10]: 
   objectid    lad19cd               lad19nm lad19nmw   bng_e   bng_n     long        lat    st_areasha    st_lengths                                           geometry
0         1  E06000001            Hartlepool     None  447160  531474 -1.27018  54.676140  9.684551e+07  50305.325058  POLYGON ((448986.025 536729.674, 453194.600 53...
1         2  E06000002         Middlesbrough     None  451141  516887 -1.21099  54.544670  5.290846e+07  34964.406313  POLYGON ((451752.698 520561.900, 452424.399 52...
2         3  E06000003  Redcar and Cleveland     None  464361  519597 -1.00608  54.567520  2.486791e+08  83939.752513  POLYGON ((451965.636 521061.756, 454348.400 52...
3         4  E06000004      Stockton-on-Tees     None  444940  518183 -1.30664  54.556911  2.071591e+08  87075.860824  POLYGON ((451965.636 521061.756, 451752.698 52...
4         5  E06000005            Darlington     None  428029  515648 -1.56835  54.535339  1.988128e+08  91926.839545  POLYGON ((419709.299 515678.298, 419162.998 51...
```

```py
# In the previous step I had no way to specify the projection used, so here I confirm that OSGB is used:
In [11]: gdf.crs                                                                                                 
Out[11]: {'init': 'epsg:27700'}
```

I checked here https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/ and this appears to be the desired projection ie OSGB.

```py
# PLOT JUST ON THE GDF (HAS PROJECTION VALUE SET), NOT THE MERGED DF AND GDF 
In [12]:gv.Polygons(gdf, vdims='lad1nm' 
    ...:            ).opts(projection=ccrs.OSGB(), 
    ...:                   tools=['hover','tap'],  
    ...:                   width=450, height=600,  
    ...:                   color_index='total_population', 
    ...:                   colorbar=True 
    ...:                  )        

DataError: Expected Polygons instance to declare two key dimensions corresponding to the geometry coordinates but 3 dimensions were found which did not refer to any columns.

GeoPandasInterface expects a list of tabular data, for more information on supported datatypes see http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Tabular_Datasets.html
```

So I thought that I might have to explicitly set the kdims:

```py
# PLOT JUST ON THE GDF, NOT THE MERGED DF AND GDF (HAS PROJECTION VALUE SET) 
In [13]: gv.Polygons(gdf, kdims=["long","lat"],vdims='lad1nm' 
    ...:            ).opts(projection=ccrs.OSGB(), 
    ...:                   tools=['hover','tap'],  
    ...:                   width=450, height=600,  
    ...:                   color_index='total_population', 
    ...:                   colorbar=True 
    ...:                  )     

DataError: Expected Polygons instance to declare two key dimensions corresponding to the geometry coordinates but 1 dimensions were found which did not refer to any columns.

GeoPandasInterface expects a list of tabular data, for more information on supported datatypes see http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Tabular_Datasets.html
```

This gave me a very similar error to before.

From reading the user guide in these error message links it says **"Tabular data has a fixed list of column headings, with values stored in an arbitrarily long list of rows. Spreadsheets, relational databases, CSV files, and many other typical data sources fit naturally into this format."**

I have attempted this with gdf created from a shapefile and demo_file from csv and feather formats and neither worked successfully.

The final thing that I tried was merging gdf with demo_file df and then attempting to plot the choropleth again:

```py
In [15]: # NEED TO MERGE demo_file DF WITH gdf BEFORE PLOTTING POLYGONS: 
    ...: finalgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.merge(demo_file, gdf, left_on="lad19_code",right_on="lad19cd")) 
    ...: finalgdf.drop(columns=["lad19_code","lad19_name"],inplace=True) 
    ...: finalgdf.head()                                                                                         
Out[15]: 
           geography  total_population  objectid    lad19cd         lad19nm lad19nmw   bng_e   bng_n     long        lat    st_areasha     st_lengths                                           geometry
0  Unitary Authority            526980        45  E06000047   County Durham     None  410381  532242 -1.84050  54.685131  2.231126e+09  264032.927496  POLYGON ((411575.398 556785.301, 413248.799 55...
1  Unitary Authority            106566         5  E06000005      Darlington     None  428029  515648 -1.56835  54.535339  1.988128e+08   91926.839545  POLYGON ((419709.299 515678.298, 419162.998 51...
2  Unitary Authority             93242         1  E06000001      Hartlepool     None  447160  531474 -1.27018  54.676140  9.684551e+07   50305.325058  POLYGON ((448986.025 536729.674, 453194.600 53...
3  Unitary Authority            140545         2  E06000002   Middlesbrough     None  451141  516887 -1.21099  54.544670  5.290846e+07   34964.406313  POLYGON ((451752.698 520561.900, 452424.399 52...
4  Unitary Authority            320274        54  E06000057  Northumberland     None  395322  600699 -2.07523  55.300369  5.033705e+09  445104.766524  MULTIPOLYGON (((391123.704 649427.867, 391525....
```

```py
In [18]: gv.Polygons(finalgdf, vdims='lad1nm', 
    ...:            ).opts(projection=ccrs.OSGB(), 
    ...:                   tools=['hover','tap'],  
    ...:                   width=450, height=600,  
    ...:                   color_index='total_population', 
    ...:                   colorbar=True 
    ...:                  )  

DataError: Expected Polygons instance to declare two key dimensions corresponding to the geometry coordinates but 3 dimensions were found which did not refer to any columns.

GeoPandasInterface expects a list of tabular data, for more information on supported datatypes see http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Tabular_Datasets.html
```

But as you can see I got the same error again.

An interesting point was that when I checked the projection used on my merged finalgdf, it came back as NoneType:

```py
In [19]: type(finalgdf.crs)                                                                                      
Out[19]: NoneType
```

So I set it to OSGB:

```py
In [20]: finalgdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:27700'} 
    ...: finalgdf.crs                                                                                            
Out[20]: {'init': 'epsg:27700'}
```

And then repeated my last plot attempt, however I just got the same error again:

```py
In [21]: gv.Polygons(finalgdf, vdims='lad1nm', 
    ...:            ).opts(projection=ccrs.OSGB(), 
    ...:                   tools=['hover','tap'],  
    ...:                   width=450, height=600,  
    ...:                   color_index='total_population', 
    ...:                   colorbar=True 
    ...:                  )                                                                                      

DataError: Expected Polygons instance to declare two key dimensions corresponding to the geometry coordinates but 3 dimensions were found which did not refer to any columns.

GeoPandasInterface expects a list of tabular data, for more information on supported datatypes see http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Tabular_Datasets.html
```

I am at a complete lose. Can anyone help me successfully recreate my UK choropleth using gv.Polygons instead of gv.Shape?

Failing that, if there was a way to successfully link my choropleth produced using gv.Shape to data tables and/or other plots as per in http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/choropleth_data_link.html then that would be great. I have tried and failed to get this working too.

Thanks

I am using OSX (10.15.2 (19C57)), firefox 74.0 (64-bit) and I am working in a Jupyter Notebook

Software Versions:
(tried to include relevent ones as couldn't fit them all in here - if I am missing any let me know and I'll add them)

```py
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py37_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
arrow-cpp                 0.13.0           py37h8cfbac2_0   
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py37_0  
cairo                     1.14.12              hc4e6be7_4  
cartopy                   0.17.0           py37haea56ea_1   
colorcet                  2.0.2                      py_0    pyviz
cython                    0.29.14          py37h0a44026_0  
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_4    conda-forge
feather-format            0.4.0                   py_1003    conda-forge
fingertips-py             0.2                      pypi_0    pypi
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
geopandas                 0.6.1                      py_0  
geos                      3.7.1                h0a44026_0  
geoviews                  1.6.5                      py_0    pyviz
geoviews-core             1.6.5                      py_0    pyviz  
holoviews                 1.12.7                     py_0    pyviz
hvplot                    0.5.2                      py_0    pyviz
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.9.0            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0  
jupyterlab                1.2.3              pyhf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0  
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0  
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h54f8f79_0   
notebook                  6.0.2                    py37_0  
numpy                     1.17.3           py37h4174a10_0  
pandas                    0.25.3           py37h0a44026_0   
panel                     0.8.0                      py_0    pyviz
param                     1.9.2                      py_0    pyviz
parquet-cpp               1.5.1                         2    conda-forge 
plotly                    4.3.0                      py_0    plotly
plotly_express            0.4.1                      py_0    plotly
proj4                     5.2.0                h0a44026_1  
pyarrow                   0.13.0           py37hb37e6aa_0    conda-forge  
python                    3.7.5                h359304d_0  
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37h0a44026_0  
scikit-learn              0.21.3           py37h27c97d8_0  
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h1410ff5_0  
seaborn                   0.9.0              pyh91ea838_1   
shapely                   1.6.4            py37he8793f5_0
```

Answer (score 0):

After further testing I created an additional question which more succinctly identifies the cause of this error and more importantly provides a solution:

[gv.Polygons DataError When Using OSGB Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60802358/gv-polygons-dataerror-when-using-osgb-projection)

Closing this question as a duplicate.